# How to upload file in React native with imagepack

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, expo

I would like to upload an image on the server, it appears in the preview, but it is sent in request.body, but I would like it to be sent in request.file. What am I doing wrong? I send it to the web in react and I have no problems, only in native react. When I send in request.body, the file goes as [Object] [Object], but I would like to extract the path and image from the file sent via mobile.

index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

import {
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Picker,
  ScrollView,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import api from "../../services/api";
import logoImg from "../../assets/icon.png";
import styles from "./styles";

export default function NewProvider() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(null);
  const [pickerVisible, setPickerVisible] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  async function handleSubmit() {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      let localUri = avatar.uri;
      let filename = localUri.split("/").pop();
      let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
      let typeImg = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;
      let formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("avatar", {
        type: typeImg,
        uri: localUri,
        name: filename,
      });
      formdata.append("name", name);
      await api.post("/providers", formdata, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }
  async function getPermissionAsync() {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
      }
    }
  }
  async function pickImage(e) {
    try {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
        base64: true,
      });
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        setAvatar(result);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("erro", err);
    }
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getPermissionAsync();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image style={styles.logoImage} source={logoImg} />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.loginTitle}>Cadastrar prestador de serviço</Text>
      <View style={styles.login}>
        <ScrollView
          vertical
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
        >
          <TextInput
            placeholder="* Nome do(a) prestador(a)/empresa"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            style={styles.inputForm}
            value={name}
           
          />
          <View
            style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.getImage} onPress={pickImage}>
              <Text style={styles.imageText}>Selecione uma imagem</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {avatar && (
              <Image
                source={{ uri: avatar.uri }}
                style={{ width: 200, height: 200, marginTop: 20 }}
              />
            )}
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.action} onPress={handleSubmit}>
            <Text style={styles.actionText}>
              {loading ? "Enviando..." : "Cadastrar"}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bye looking at your code I think there is a better way of doing it.

First I recommend creating a function to handleImageUpload
as shown below

```
handleUploadPhoto = () => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    body: createFormData(this.state.photo, { userId: "123" })
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log("upload succes", response);
      alert("Upload success!");
      this.setState({ photo: null });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("upload error", error);
      alert("Upload failed!");
    });
};
```

This will force react native to send Image as request.file not request.file and if that all goes well it check your console and see if it says SUCSESS!

And to call it, you could use something like this

```
<Button title="Upload" onPress={this.handleUpload} />
```

Now remember THIS IS AN EXAMPLE change it to your needs.